# is-invalid wont show up naturally

Tags: html, laravel, bootstrap-4, laravel-jetstream

So i struggle with this, for a day | I use Laravel/Jetstream 8.x

i make a form for register but is-invalid wont show in the browser, bellow is example of code that wont show up

```
<div class="col">
    <input class="form-control @error('nama_f') is-invalid @enderror" type="text" id="name_f" name="name_f" placeholder="Front name">
    @error ('nama_f')<div class="invalid-feedback">this is invalid</div> @enderror
</div>
```

here's what the browser respond

```
<div class="col">
    <input class="form-control " type="text" id="name_f" name="name_f" placeholder="Front name">
</div>
```

it's put a space so it mean its there but somehow no

i tried few stuff like @if

```
    @if ($errors->any()) 
        <div style="color: red; font-size:15px">
            Please choose a username.
        </div>
    @endif
```

this work fine, but will show up when any error appear which a no

also Jetstream default is nice, but showing up name that shouldn't show up
i have no idea how to custom it, but i can hide it so thats why i use is-invalid
[*pic when it show default error msg *](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewVjg.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo.

`@error('nama_f') is-invalid @enderror`

should be

`@error('name_f') is-invalid @enderror`